# How can I find and return my div element with rails and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am trying to build a piece of javascript that take the url from the web page looks to see if there was an anchor included in the address then it will scroll down the page to the anchor, I have to do this because bootstraps sticky-top nav blocks the view of the element I am trying to view.

My js looks like

```
findLink = function(){
  link = document.location.href
  parseLink(link)
}

parseLink = function(link) {
  if (link.split('').includes('#')) {
    post_id = link.split('#')[1];
    moveLink(post_id)
  }
}

moveLink = function(post_id){
  element = $('#+post_id').get()

}

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', findLink()) ||
$(document).on('page:load', findLink())
```

my issue is that even if I try to find

```
console.log($('#my_id')) # returns jQuery.fn.init {}
console.log($('#my_id').get()) # returns an empty []
```

I get two empty arrays.
I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Try returning `return  $('#' + post_id).get()`

Comment: You should't add the listener to the `turbolinks:load` event using jquery's ready callback, since the event could be triggered before jquery loads. Use `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', findLink)` and you don't really need jquery to get the element, use `document.getElementById(post_id)` instead, it will be faster and you don't need to wait for jquery to load to scroll to the post.

Comment: You are invoking `findLink` immediately on page load rather than passing reference to the event listener

Comment: Also, you can use `window.location.hash` to get that part of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some JS its not perfect but it gets the job done.

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
  link = document.location.href
  parseLink(link)
});

parseLink = function(link) {
  if (link.split('').includes('#')) {
    post_id = link.split('#')[1];
    moveLink(post_id)
  }
}

moveLink = function(post_id){
  element = document.getElementById(post_id)
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(element).position().top -= 200
   });
}
```